# How can I pipe a Zip into another Zip

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, gulp-zip

I need to zip a certain set of folders and files to a file called Resources.zip and then have the zip nested inside a final zip called Install.zip.

Here is what I have and I have no idea why the first merge is not showing in the final zip.

```
    var gulp = require('gulp'),
    msbuild = require('gulp-msbuild'),
    nugetRestore = require('gulp-nuget-restore'),    
    cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    assemblyInfo = require('gulp-dotnet-assembly-info'),
    config = require('./package.json'),
    zip = require('gulp-zip'),
    filter = require('gulp-filter'),
    merge = require('merge2'),
    markdown = require('gulp-markdown'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    gutil = require('gulp-util'),
    path = require('path');

gulp.task('packageInstall', function() {
    var packageName = config.dnnModule.fullName + '_' + config.version;

    var jsFilter = filter(['**/js/*.js', '!**/js/*.min.js'], { restore: true });
    var cssFilter = filter(['**/*.css'], { restore: true });

    return merge(
        merge(
        gulp.src([
        config.dnnModule.pathToPublish + '/**/{*.png,*.gif,*.svn,*.jpg}',
        config.dnnModule.pathToPublish + '/**/*.cshtml',
        config.dnnModule.pathToPublish + '/**/{*.aspx,*.ascx,*.asmx}',
        config.dnnModule.pathToPublish + '/**/*.css',
        config.dnnModule.pathToPublish + '/**/{*,htm,*.html}',
        config.dnnModule.pathToPublish + '/**/*.resx',
        config.dnnModule.pathToPublish + '/**/*.js',
        config.dnnModule.pathToPublish + '/**/*.txt',
        '!' + config.dnnModule.pathToPublish + '/**/web.config',
        '!' + config.dnnModule.pathToPublish + '/**/gulpfile.js',
        '!' + config.dnnModule.pathToPublish + '/**/{bin,bin/**}',
        '!' + config.dnnModule.pathToPublish + '/**/{Providers,Providers/**}'
    ])
    .pipe(cssFilter)
    .pipe(cleanCSS())
    .pipe(cssFilter.restore)
    .pipe(jsFilter)
    .pipe(uglify().on('error', gutil.log))
    .pipe(jsFilter.restore)
    )
    .pipe(zip('Resources.zip')),

    gulp.src([
        config.dnnModule.pathToPublish + '/**/TestMvs.dll',
        config.dnnModule.pathToPublish + '/Providers/**/*.SqlDataProvider',
        config.dnnModule.pathToPublish + '/License.txt',
        config.dnnModule.pathToPublish + '/ReleaseNotes.txt'
    ]),
    gulp.src(config.dnnModule.pathToSupplementaryFiles + '/ReleaseNotes.md')
    .pipe(markdown())
    .pipe(rename('ReleaseNotes.txt'))
    )
    .pipe(zip('Install.zip'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dnnModule.packagesPath));
});
```

After I run the task I get a zip file, but it does not contain the resources.zip from the first stream, it only contains the files from the second stream. I have tested the first stream in its own task and wrote out the file to disk and it produces the zip correctly in that instance. I just can't get them to nest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to switch from the merge2 package to the event-stream package. After I did this and updated my merge calls to es.merge everything started working.